# Asterisk NOT FOUND answer on OPTION request

Tags: asterisk

Remote server send me OPTION package, but my asterisk server send "404 NOT FOUND" response. Is there an option in sip.conf or something else?

```
sip.conf
    [remote-server]
    type=friend
    host=10.1.1.1
    context=test
    qualify=yes
    disallow=all
    insecure=invite,port
    allowguest=yes
    nat=force_rport,comedia
    allow=g729
    allow=alaw
    allow=ulaw
    allow=gsm
```

request:

```
OPTIONS sip:10.1.1.1:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.1.1:5060
Call-ID: XXXXXX@YYYYY
From: <sip:AAA@10.1.1.1>;tag=1oz35123
To: <sip:10.1.1.2>
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Contact: <sip:10.1.1.1:36808;transport=udp>;expires=65535
Accept: application/sdp
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0
```

response:

```
SIP/2.0 404 Not Found
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.1.1:5060
From: <sip:<AAA@10.1.1.1>;tag=1oz35123
To: <sip:10.1.1.2>;tag=as53fc8169
Call-ID: XXXXXX@YYYYY
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: As the `[asterisk]` tag states, questions like this are off-topic for StackOverflow. Please ask your question over on SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

I fixed with adding extension.conf to

```
[default]
exten => s,1,NoOp( DEFAULT context )
```

Answer (score 2):

NOT FOUND answer on options is OKAY for most switches.

If you want do s-extension in default context, for security purposes better put Hangup.